# How do I keep a group header in crystal reports from appeaing when unnecessary?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I am running a report on multiple salespersons and their multiple clients. I have a group header, which includes the name of the salesperson for that group, and a secondary group header, which includes the name of each of the salesperson's clients and all their info as well as headings for the columns with information.
I've set up both group headings to appear at the top of every page. It works for the most part with the group header at the top of every page along with the corresponding secondary group header for the particular client being reported on. However, I've run into a small problem. Sometimes when the next group for a for the next client is started it's toward the end of the page so that the end of page has the secondary group header with none of the details only to repeat at the top of the next page with the corresponding details. I don't want to start a new page for each client as some clients don't have a lot of information and multiple clients can be included on a page. How do I set it up so that if there is not enough space on a page for any details, the secondary header does not appear until the next page?

Thank you.

Comment: Any picture of your problem would be nice to get familiar with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that "keep it together" was only clicked for the main group not the subgroup that I was worried about. So I clicked it and that solved the problem